# How to get only latest object in this case?

Tags: django

How to get only latest object in this case?

```
{% for entry in instance.event.myevent_set.all %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

My try:

```
{% for entry in instance.event.myevent_set.all[0] %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

but of course not work.

**models:**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MyEvent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

and my **urls:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=MyEvent.objects.all(),
            context_object_name='latest_entry_list',
            template_name="blog/index.html"
        ),
        name="blog_list"),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$', 'event.views.single_event'),
)
```

Comment: myevent_set is ordered by desc time? If so you can do `myevent_set.all.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
instance.event.myevent_set.all.0
```

or

```
instance.event.myevent_set.all|first
```

Comment: Well, since you're only getting one element, you don't need the for loop, clearly.